# PLSQL trigger for each row set new.column not working

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I'm trying to calculate the total value in the table as I insert all subject values.
This is my plsql code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER stud_marks before INSERT OR UPDATE ON student_report 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
set new.total := :new.sub1 + :new.sub2 + :new.sub3;
END;
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
 Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

 SQL> show error; Errors for TRIGGER STUD_MARKS:

 LINE/COL ERROR
 -------- ----------------------------------------------------------------- 
 2/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored 2/5      PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
```

Comment: SET is not a PL/SQL command. You just need a straightforward assignment: `:new.total := :new.sub1 + :new.sub2 + :new.sub3;`

Comment: I tried removing SET still error is coming`SQL> show error
Errors for TRIGGER STUD_REP:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/1      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
2/1      PLS-00201: identifier 'NEW.TOTAL' must be declared`

Comment: and if I declare total then also the same error is coming

Comment: @Ajax you're lacking semicolon:
:new.total := :new.sub1 + :new.sub2 + :new.sub3

Comment: Yes. If you look at my code I corrected that missing semi-colon. I guess I should have made that point more explicit.

Comment: thanks it was the semi colon... man in PL/SQL its very difficult to understand the error message..

Comment: Unless  it's a solution to homework, you absolutely don't need a Trigger for this case. Take a look at [**Virtual Columns**](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1)

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER stud_marks before INSERT OR UPDATE ON student_report 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
:new.total := :new.sub1 + :new.sub2 + :new.sub3;
END;

before insert ( :new=new inserted value :old=null);
before update ( :new=new updated value :old=old value);
```